# Example of a prepared INSERT statement using ruby pg gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

Did some googling for about half a day and I can't find any sample of a prepared INSERT statement using the pg gem (postgresql ruby gem).

I tried this (after looking at the gem docs):

```
def test2
    conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'db1' )
    conn.prepare("statement1", 'INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, profile) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
pgtest.rb:19:in `prepare': ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," (PG::Error)
LINE 1: INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, profile) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
                                                        ^
from pgtest.rb:19:in `test2'
from pgtest.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the whole file please? That might help, since its a syntax error — it may have started farther back

Comment: @Jwosty: The `ERROR: ... (PG::Error)` indicates that error is coming from `pg` rather than Ruby.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense... It looked like it was a syntax mistake on the OP's part. I didn't realize that the gem was throwing the error (I've never used this one before); thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `pg` gem wants you to use numbered placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ...) rather than positional placeholders (`?`):

```
conn = PG.connect(:dbname => 'db1')
conn.prepare('statement1', 'insert into table1 (id, name, profile) values ($1, $2, $3)')
conn.exec_prepared('statement1', [ 11, 'J.R. "Bob" Dobbs', 'Too much is always better than not enough.' ])
```

The [fine manual](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#prepare-instance_method) has this to say:

> `- (PGresult) prepare(stmt_name, sql[, param_types ])`
>   [...]
>   PostgreSQL bind parameters are represented as $1, $1, $2, etc., inside the SQL query.

And again for [`exec_prepared`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#exec_prepared-instance_method):

> PostgreSQL bind parameters are represented as $1, $1, $2, etc., inside the SQL query. The 0th element of the params array is bound to $1, the 1st element is bound to $2, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Doh, I don't know how I missed that!

Comment: When is it worth it to prepare the statement prior to executing it?

Comment: @Martin: If you want to execute the same statement several times with different values. Some DB interfaces require explicit prepared statement use to use placeholders at all but the `pg` gem lets you use placeholders with [`exec`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#exec-instance_method).

Comment: @mu Thanks!  I ran a small experiment: I ran a program 3 times with `exec`; about 1600 `exec` calls.  I converted the `exec` calls to `prepare`, and `exec_prepared`, and reran program a 3 times.  On average, the version with `prepare` calls was a bit slower, 1%.  I remain stumped.

Comment: @Martin were you using different parameter values for all of the 1,600 exec calls?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, I was using different values.  However, I realize now that the latency was because they were writes.  It masked the latency of preparing.  When I do it with reads, I get a noticeable improvement.

Comment: Nice answer! Want to add that prepared statements live only during and within SESSION. So you can not create permanent prepared statement. I think this is a bit related to question so decided to mention for those who are not aware of this, like me 5 minutes ago.